# How to query hdfs file with presto

Tags: hdfs, presto, apache-drill

I am trying to query hdfs file with Presto like Apache Drill. I have searched but found anything due to lack of Presto resources. I can query hdfs data with hive connector, no problem with that. But I want to query a file in hdfs that not controlled by hive. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You can use Hive connector with

```
hive.metastore=file
hive.metastore.catalog.dir=/home/youruser/metastore
```

This will create "embedded metastore" with `/home/youruser/metastore` directory as the storage. Then you can declare your table as if you used Hive metastore and read from it.

Comment: where to define these configs? I put catalog/hive.properties but presto couldn't start.

Comment: Yes, `hive.properties`. I don't think SO is best place for troubleshooting. I invite you to `#troubleshooting` on Presto Community Slack https://prestosql.io/slack.html. See you there!